# What navigation short-cuts exist in aws UI console for power users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, shortcut

I've seen a couple of ways to navigate.
How many different ways exist for power users in 2019 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways!

**1. Services Dropdown**
First of all there is the menu system you get from clicking `services`
It lists most of the services for you to click on one.
Below you can see several of the Compute Menu Items - EC2, Lightsail, etc.
[image]

**2. Input Search Field**
Next you can type the service you are looking for in the text box, e.g.
[image]

**3. Recent History**
Next you can use the recent history of functions that shows on the left for recently used functions
[image]

**4. Bookmarks**
Finally (and my favorite) you can 'pin' commonly used areas to the top bar, similar to a browser bookmark bar.  You can have icons, text or both, for example I have just Icons to squeeze more in.  Click the thumbtack icon to change which ones you have:
[image]
Of course you can also have your classic browser bookmarks for the various areas too and you may prefer all your bookmarks in one place.  Or are ok with them being in two places as well.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I create my own browser shortcut in Chrome's "Manage Search Engines", set to:

```
https://console.aws.amazon.com/%s/home?region=ap-southeast-2
```

The `%s` in the middle can be entered in the browser address bar, so I can instantly jump to any service by typing the search keyword and the service name, eg `con s3` or `con sqs`.

Comment: In Firefox you can do the same usign Bookmarks and keywords for bookmarks: https://superuser.com/a/7374/602868